# Unable to filter search results

Tags: java, android

The app is crashing once I click the search button. As a result I am unable to filter the search results.

This is my Recycler View

```
public class RecyclerView_Config {
            private Context sContext;
            private SupplierAdapter supAdapter;

            public void setConfig(RecyclerView recyclerView, Context context, List<supplierDB> suppliers, List<String> keys) {
                sContext = context;
                supAdapter = new SupplierAdapter(suppliers, keys);
                recyclerView.setLayoutManager(new LinearLayoutManager(context));
                recyclerView.setAdapter(supAdapter);
            }

            class SupplierView extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder {
                private TextView pc, pd, cn, ca, lno, mno, email;
                private String key;

                public SupplierView(ViewGroup parent) {
                    super(LayoutInflater.from(sContext).inflate(R.layout.supplier_list_2, parent, false));

                    pc = (TextView)itemView.findViewById(R.id.pCat_View);
                    pd = (TextView)itemView.findViewById(R.id.pDesc_View);
                    cn = (TextView)itemView.findViewById(R.id.cName_View);
                    ca = (TextView)itemView.findViewById(R.id.cAddr_View);
                    lno = (TextView)itemView.findViewById(R.id.lNo_View);
                    mno = (TextView)itemView.findViewById(R.id.mNo_View);
                    email = (TextView)itemView.findViewById(R.id.eMail_View);

                    itemView.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                        @Override
                        public void onClick(View view) {
                            Intent intent = new Intent(sContext, viewSupplier.class);
                            intent.putExtra("key", key);
                            intent.putExtra("pCategory", pc.getText().toString());
                            intent.putExtra("pDesc", pd.getText().toString());
                            intent.putExtra("cName", cn.getText().toString());
                            intent.putExtra("cAddr", ca.getText().toString());
                            //intent.putExtra("landline", lno.getText().toString());
                            //intent.putExtra("mobile", mno.getText().toString());
                            intent.putExtra("email", email.getText().toString());

                            sContext.startActivity(intent);
                        }
                    });
                }

                public void bind(supplierDB supplier, String key) {
                    pc.setText(supplier.getpCategory());
                    pd.setText(supplier.getpDesc());
                    cn.setText(supplier.getcName());
                    ca.setText(supplier.getcAddr());
                    lno.setText(supplier.getLandline().toString());
                    mno.setText(supplier.getMobile().toString());
                    email.setText(supplier.getEmail());
                    this.key = key;
                }
            }

            class SupplierAdapter extends RecyclerView.Adapter<SupplierView> implements Filterable {
                private List<supplierDB> supplierList;
                private List<String> keys;
                private List<supplierDB> supplierListFull;

                public SupplierAdapter(List<supplierDB> supplierList, List<String> keys) {
                    this.supplierList = supplierList;
                    this.keys = keys;
                    supplierListFull = new ArrayList<>(supplierList);
                }

                @Override
                public SupplierView onCreateViewHolder(ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {
                    return new SupplierView(parent);
                }

                @Override
                public void onBindViewHolder(@NonNull SupplierView holder, int position) {
                    holder.bind(supplierList.get(position), keys.get(position));
                }

                @Override
                public int getItemCount() {
                    return supplierList.size();
                }

                @Override
                public Filter getFilter() {
                    return supplierFilter;
                }

                private Filter supplierFilter = new Filter() {
                    @Override
                    protected FilterResults performFiltering(CharSequence charSequence) {
                        List<supplierDB> filteredList = new ArrayList<>();

                        if(charSequence == null || charSequence.length() == 0) {
                            filteredList.addAll(supplierListFull);
                        } else {
                            String filterPattern = charSequence.toString().toLowerCase().trim();

                            for(supplierDB supplier : supplierListFull) {
                                if(supplier.getcName().toLowerCase().contains(filterPattern)) {
                                    filteredList.add(supplier);
                                }
                            }
                        }

                        FilterResults results = new FilterResults();
                        results.values = filteredList;

                        return results;
                    }

                    @Override
                    protected void publishResults(CharSequence charSequence, FilterResults filterResults) {
                        supplierList.clear();
                        supplierList.addAll((List) filterResults.values);
                        notifyDataSetChanged();
                    }
                };
            }
        }
```

This is my Main Activity

```
public class Main2Activity extends AppCompatActivity implements NavigationView.OnNavigationItemSelectedListener {
        private DrawerLayout drawer;
        RecyclerView_Config.SupplierAdapter supAdapter;

        protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
            super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
            setContentView(R.layout.main2activity);

            Toolbar tb = findViewById(R.id.tBar);
            setSupportActionBar(tb);

            drawer = findViewById(R.id.drawer_layout);
            NavigationView navigationView = findViewById(R.id.nav_view);
            navigationView.setNavigationItemSelectedListener(this);

            ActionBarDrawerToggle toggle = new ActionBarDrawerToggle(this, drawer, tb, R.string.navigation_drawer_open, R.string.navigation_drawer_close);
            drawer.addDrawerListener(toggle);
            toggle.syncState();

            if(savedInstanceState == null) {
                getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction().replace(R.id.fragment_container, new addSupplier()).commit();
                navigationView.setCheckedItem(R.id.nav_add_supplier);
            }
        }


        @Override
        public boolean onNavigationItemSelected(@NonNull MenuItem menuItem) {
            switch (menuItem.getItemId()) {
                case R.id.nav_add_supplier:
                    getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction().replace(R.id.fragment_container, new addSupplier()).commit();
                    break;
                case R.id.nav_view_supplier:
                    getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction().replace(R.id.fragment_container, new supplierList()).commit();
                    break;
                //case R.id.nav_view_schedule:
                    //getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction().replace(R.id.fragment_container, new viewSupplier()).commit();
                    //break;
            }

            drawer.closeDrawer(GravityCompat.START);
            return true;
        }

        public void onBackPressed() {
            if(drawer.isDrawerOpen(GravityCompat.START)) {
                drawer.closeDrawer(GravityCompat.START);
            } else {
                super.onBackPressed();
            }
        }

        @Override
        public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
            MenuInflater inflater = getMenuInflater();
            inflater.inflate(R.menu.supplier_menu, menu);

            MenuItem searchItem = menu.findItem(R.id.action_search);
            SearchView searchView = (SearchView) searchItem.getActionView();

            searchView.setOnQueryTextListener(new SearchView.OnQueryTextListener() {
                @Override
                public boolean onQueryTextSubmit(String s) {
                    return false;
                }

                @Override
                public boolean onQueryTextChange(String s) {
                    supAdapter.getFilter().filter(s);
                    return false;
                }
            });
            return true;
        }
    }
```

This is the error I am getting:

> java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method
>   'android.widget.Filter
>   com.example.ashvins.suppliermanagement.RecyclerView_Config$SupplierAdapter.getFilter()'
>   on a null object reference

Comment: which line did the error pointed to? Did you add it in `supplier_menu.xml`?

Comment: Please attach the full error stack trace but not only the error message. From the full stack trace, it's possible to find a line in which this error happened. 

Also do you try to use step-by-step debug of that in Android Studio?

Comment: @JohnJoe Yes I added it in supplier_menu.xml. The error is from line 84 of Main Activity which is supAdapter.getFilter().filter(s);

Comment: Perhaps you  miss to initialize supAdapter in MainActivity

Comment: @JohnJoe Can you please tell me how to initialize it in Main Activity? I don't know how to do it. Thanks.

Comment: @AshvinNanda can you post your project to github? So I can check.

Comment: @JohnJoe https://github.com/AshvinNanda/SupplierManagement

Comment: have you solved?

Comment: @JohnJoe No I couldn't still solve it. Did you check my project in github?

Comment: Ya. I busy with my job. Will help if i am free.

Comment: So you want filter supplierList which is in view supplier fragment,right?

Comment: @JohnJoe No I want to filter supplier list in recycler view. Once I click an item in list view it takes me to view supplier fragment. I don't have any issues in that fragment. The problem is that I didn't initialize the adapter properly in the Main Activity as you said before. I don't know how to initialize that adapter in Main Activity which is from RecyclerView_Config class.

Comment: Why don't you just only show the search bar in supplierList fragment?

Comment: @JohnJoe I did that afterwards but I am having the same issue there as well.

Comment: @AshvinNanda I will help you once I back from work today

Comment: @JohnJoe Thanks a lot brother.

Comment: I have make the search bar only visible in View Supplier fragment. No more crash, but the filter not working. You can try to fix. Here my github repo https://github.com/tony123S/Filter

Comment: @JohnJoe The app is not crashing and the filter is working now. Thanks a lot.